# Radon-Nikodým-like theorem for Radon measures

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, measure-theory

Let $(E,d)$ be a metric space, $\mu$ be a nonnegative Radon$^1$ measure on $\mathcal B(E)$ and $\nu$ be a finite (signed) Radon measure on $\mathcal B(E)$.

> I'm searching for a Radon-Nikodým-like theorem yielding a sufficient condition to ensure that there is a locally $\mu$-integrable $f:E\to\mathbb R$ with $$\int g\:{\rm d}\nu=\int fg\:{\rm d}\mu\;\;\;\text{for all }g\in C_c(E)\tag1.$$

*Context*: Given $p\in[1,\infty)$ and $q\in(1,\infty]$ with $p^{-1}+q^{-1}=1$, I would like to prove that $L^p(\mu)'$ is isometrically isomorphic to $L^q(\mu)$ by the following argumentation: If $\mathcal M(E)$ denotes the space of finite (signed) measures on $\mathcal B(E)$, we know that $$\langle f,\nu\rangle:=\int f\:{\rm d}\nu\;\;\;\text{for }(f,\nu)\in C_b(E)\times\mathcal M(E)$$ is a duality pairing. Given a nonnegative Radon measure $\mu$ on $\mathcal B(E)$ and $\varphi\in L^p(\mu)'$, we easily see that $$Lf:=\langle f,\varphi\rangle\;\;\;\text{for }f\in C_b(E)$$ is a linear functional which is continuous with respect to the topology $\sigma(C_b(E),\mathcal M(E))$. So, there is a $\nu\in\mathcal M(E)$ with $$Lf=\langle f,\nu\rangle\;\;\;\text{for all }f\in C_b(E).$$ Now I would like to find a condition ensuring that $\nu$ has a density with respect to $\mu$.

*Remark*: Please don't stick to close to the stated assumptions. I'm willing to impose further assumptions if they lead to a positive result.

---

$^1$ i.e. for all $B\in\mathcal B(E)$ and $\varepsilon>0$, there is a compact $K\subseteq E$ with $\mu(B\setminus K)<\varepsilon$.

Comment: Something is wrong in your footnote defining Radon: B is never used...

Comment: In (1) do you mean $C_c(E)$ or $C_b(E)$?

Comment: If I understand the intent of your definition, then a Radon measure is $\sigma$-finite.  Since the intended fact about duality of $\mathrm L^p$ spaces is true for all $\sigma$-finite measures, what's the point of imposing additional hypotheses to give a new proof of it?

Comment: Do you want to use the lattice structure of $L^p(\mu)'$? Then $\varphi$ writes as a difference of positive functionals, $\varphi=\varphi_+-\varphi_-$,  and it's sufficient to consider the case of $\varphi\ge0$. Once you got $\nu$ (not completely clear whence), it seems easy that $\nu<<\mu$, so that RN applies. For any $\phi\ge0$, any *closed* $\mu$-null set $F$ and $\epsilon>0$ there is a continuous $f$ with $\chi_F\le f$ and $\|f\|_p<\epsilon$. So $\nu(F)\le \|\varphi\|_{L^p(\mu)'}\epsilon$, whence $\nu(F)=0$. By the regularity, $(\mu(S)=0\implies \nu(S)=0)$ holds true for any $S\in B(E)$.

Comment: @NateEldredge In $(1)$, I mean $C_c(E)$ to ensure that the integral on the rhs is well-defined ($f$ is only integrable on compact subsets).

Comment: @MatthewDaws Yes, sorry. It should be $\mu(B\setminus K)$; not $\mu(K^c)$.

Comment: @PietroMajer Clearly, for any closed $F$ and open $G$ with $F\subseteq G$, we find a continuous function $0\le f\le 1$ with $\left.f\right|_F=1$ and $\left.f\right|_{E\setminus G}=0$, but how do you ensure that $\left\|f\right|_p<\varepsilon$ as well?

Comment: @PietroMajer This would be clear to me if we could show that, given $F$, there always is an open $G$ with $\mu(G\setminus F)<\varepsilon$ (this is always the case, when $\mu$ is finite, but I'm unsure whether it remains true in general), since then $\mu|f|^p\le\mu(F)+\varepsilon$.

Comment: Then it seems to me that you should assume $E$ is locally compact; otherwise $C_c(E)$ may be too small to be useful.  For instance, in an infinite-dimensional Banach space $E$, we have $C_c(E) = 0$, so the conclusion is trivially true for every $\mu, \nu$, taking $f$ to be any function you want.

Comment: Is it really a duality pairing? I suspect (though I'm not sure) there exists a nonzero Borel measure which is zero when integrated against any continuous bounded function, if you don't assume things like separability or local compactness.